# Can I use <h4> to demonstrate subheading in html?

Tags: html

[image]

JANE DOETTE is for h1, and can I use h4 to deal with FRONT-END.

Definately, h1 is for the main heading, but when it comes to subheading, I don't know whether I can use these h* to deal with that.

According to W3C standards, all the h tags have some semantic meaning. So is it suitable to use h4 to deal with subheading in this case?or use other things, such as p tag or span to deal with it.

sorry for the grammar mistakes, cause I am not a native speakers. If there are any mistakes, I'm very grateful for you helping me correct it.

Comment: yes you can use h4 for subheadings..it is totally semantic ...This link could be of some help tp you http://ablognotlimited.com/articles/the-beauty-of-semantic-markup-part-3-headings

Comment: Whats the website going to be about?

Comment: [The HTML5 spec says](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#headings-and-sections) "h1–h6 elements must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for a new section or subsection." Your example is a tagline and so using h4 there is invalid.

Comment: yes,I think HTML5 spec is the authority.

Comment: @Alohci, what would be the solution? I have the same issue and I wrapped the subheading in `<span>` tags (which are styled by CSS to look like a subheading); like `<h1>Title<span class='subHeading'>Subtitle</span></h1>`. Would this be semantically correct?

Comment: @JAT86 - The current HTML5 recommendation is at [4.13.1. Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines](https://w3c.github.io/html/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines)

Comment: The W3C recommendations for dealing with subheadings have moved: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [article](http://ablognotlimited.com/articles/the-beauty-of-semantic-markup-part-3-headings) Geeky links to in their comment, I think it can be summed up for you with this paragraph

> As far as I can glean, the "best practices" for indicating content
>   structure is simply to use `<h1>` for the most important information,
>   `<h2>` for less important information and so on. Also, it is probably
>   best to not skip any heading levels, such as going from `<h1>` to `<h3>`.
>   But that's it.

Comment: I concur - the semantically correct approach is to use the headings in order - meaning that if you go straight from H1 to H4 - skipping the H2 and 3 - then it is not semantically as correct as it could be. This is an example of " you can do it - but you shouldn't do it".